# Responding to LDAP queries in a .NET Server

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I am looking for a small sample demonstrating how to respond to incoming LDAP queries.

Is there any such sample available that would demonstrate such thing? 
Is there functionality built in the .NET Framework library?

Comment: Install [Active Directory LDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733064%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) ?!?!?

Comment: I installed AD LDS and tested it. Now I would like to write a similar server that speaks LDAP. Nothing fancy or full fledged like AD LDS, just listens on ports, replies to request. I am looking for samples to start with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your LDAP client requires a full server installation, OpenLDAP might be satisfactory. If the client can be tested with an in-memory server (which will not require a full server installation yet provides a fully-functional LDAP server installation), use the [in-memory server](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/in-memory-directory-server/) provided by the UnboundID LDAP SDK.

Comment: Hi Terry, Do you have experience with the UnboundID LDAP SDK? Is it suitable to create custom LDAP servers?

Comment: The in-memory directory server creates a directory server running in a JVM as noted in the blog entry (link in my answer above).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I accepted your answer! I will try to port this to .NET

Comment: The link in the blog post to the source code seems to be broken!

Comment: Thank you, it was broken. I corrected the [link to the sample code for the in-memory directory server](https://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/samplecode/listener/LdapListenerExample.java).

Comment: Gyurisc, were you able to Port it to .net?